# Where and how can I save a mathematica package

Tags: packages, save

I want to save a mathematica package and then i want to extract and run it from there.
How can i do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "save" and "run"? Did you write the code yourself or are you trying to install a package you downloaded? Are you trying to _run_ a script or are you trying to _load_ a package, to gain access to the functions provided by it?

Comment: I am trying to save (i suppose to a folder) and then by <<name,, or with another way

Comment: I am trying to save ( i suppose to a folder-which folder?), and then maybe by <<name or with another way to run and use it.

Comment: Henrik's answer is what you need then.

Comment: Okay, I had at the SARAH download ZIP. (From an earlier post, I guess that what all this is about.). The first problem is that the unzipped folder has the version number in it. The SARAH developers also violated several other requirement for a package. Loading it with `Needs` thus does not work as expected. The Readme.txt file in the SARAH directory says you are supposed to load SARAH into _Mathematica_ with `Get[FileNameJoin[{path, "SARAH.m"}]]`, where `path` is the full path of the package's directory.

Comment: Most annoyingly, the first thing the package wants to do is ``Remove[JLink`Fields];``, but that is a protected symbol, so _Mathematica_ refused and issues an error message. Not sure whether this really breaks anything. I cannot be bothered with such a brittle design. If you need further assistance, plaase ask the developers for help.

Comment: It still doesn't work! It shows me that FileName is not a string.

Comment: Thank you Henrik, anyway. Iwill still try to find a solution. Your comments have been very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. I ran about such a FileName issue with some other older packages ("KnotTheory`" to be precise). But I was able to load the newest version of SARAH on macos. Maybe this is something that depends on the operating system? Or maybe you have to install some further dependencies (e.g., a C compiler)? But before I continue guessing, you should check the package's documentation and its FAQ page. If that does not help as well, please contact the package authors directly.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy the package's folder into `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]`. Then run `Needs[name]`, where name is the package's name with a backtick `` "`" `` added at the end.

Comment: I have saved in Mathematica-Addons-Applications folder, the package, then the first command works but the Needs command doesn;'t work, It shows me Context "Filename" was not created when Needs was evaluated